# Javascript - I am trying to build the function passingGrades to filter out low grades (<=70) in an array of grades, but it's not working.

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

The code below does not work and I can't figure out why. Can anyone help?

```
var grades = [];

var passingGrades = function(grades) {

  for (i=0; i < grades.length; i++){

    console.log(grades.filter(function(grades[i]) {

      return grades[i] >= 70;
    }));
  }
};


passingGrades([63, 75, 39, 88, 94, 100, 24]);
```

Comment: Why are you manually iterating `grades` with a for-loop, and using `filter`?

Comment: `filter()` returns a new Array, leaves the original one unchanged.

Comment: And you never return from `passingGrades`. You'll likely need to do that too, depending on what your expected behaviour is.

Comment: Here's how: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/235dn7ae/

Comment: @ChrisG Why an external link, if you can do it here in an answer?

Comment: "Does not work" is something you should avoid in ALL your posts. Instead, explain how it doesn't work, what's the expected output, what's the actual behavior? Any error messages? In this case it's simple, but you should get used to asking well posed questions.

Comment: @JuanMendes Because I believe that this question is off-topic for Stack Overflow, and answering it is enabling people who haven't done enough work before posting here.

Comment: @ChrisG Then you should mark it as so? I agree that it's not a well asked/researched question, but if you're going to give them the answer, may as well do it here, instead of clicking on a link? You can at least explain what the problem was

Comment: @JuanMendes Like I said, posting an answer suggests that the question is fine, and here to stay. The fact that the question is bad (in terms of SO) and going to be removed soon doesn't mean the OP doesn't deserve an answer though, so I'm giving it in a comment.

Comment: @JuanMendes and ChrisG, Thank you both for your feedback. It's my first time using Stack Overflow and I will make sure to post my questions better in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to return the filtered array, a new one is created by the  `filter` method.

Side note: Don't use a global variable with the same name as a local variable!

```js
var passingGrades = function(grades) {
  return grades.filter((grade) => grade >= 70);
};
console.log(passingGrades([63, 75, 39, 88, 94, 100, 24]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Array methods like `filter` and `map` automatically iterate over every item within them(that's what makes them so powerful) and, when called, they return a new array. This means there's no need for a `for` loop as well.  What you have currently would be roughly the equivalent of:

```
for(i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
 for(i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
  if(grades[i] > 70) {
   ...
  }
 }
}
```

That's unnecessary.

Furthermore since you're simply filtering an array that you are already passing into the function you might as well just return the filtered array immediately. To do this we just `return` the `grades.filter` result.

Lastly the `function` that you're placing within `.filter` is what will be called on each item within the array you passed in. The parameter you provide is a reference to each individual item as this iteration occurs. This is why `grades[i]` makes no sense, it's a pointer to the referenced item, so you can simply call it `grade`.

In simpler terms we are saying hey, `grades`, filter everything within yourself and for each `grade` determine if it's greater than 70. Return an array only containing these *filtered* items

```js
var passingGrades = function(grades) {
return grades.filter(function(grade) {
      return grade >= 70;
    });
}


console.log( passingGrades([63, 75, 39, 88, 94, 100, 24]) );
```